# How to integrate function with value insert?

Tags: r

I would like to integrate dnorm(X, theta, 10), whose X value is data that I will insert, and theta is a variable. I have 100 data, and I want to sum the integrals of dnorm(data[i], theta, 10) from one to hundred. So I declared the function like the below.

```
integrand <- function(theta, X){
  f2 <- dnorm(X, mean = theta, sd = 10)
  return(f2)
}

sum = 0
for(i in 1 : 100){
term = integrate(integrand(X = data[i]), -Inf, Inf)
sum = sum + term
}
```

But the error came out

> Error in dnorm(theta, mean = theta_0, sd = sd_0) : argument "theta" is missing, with no default

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something along the lines:

```
data <- runif(100)

integrand <- function(theta, X) dnorm(X, mean = theta, sd = 10)

ss <- 0 
for(i in 1:100){
     ss  <-  ss + integrate(f=integrand, lower=-Inf, upper=Inf,
                            X=data[i])$value
}
```

But I don't think that integrating a distribution from `-Inf` to `Inf` is very interesting.